# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName() Error from Tomcat 9 | method is present is servlet-api.jar

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am deploying my Java application (servlets) on Tomcat 9 on Windows. While deploying. I get the below error from Tomcat. The build file is of type WAR.

[image: ERROR]

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mbas6]]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5094)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
  ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1355)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  ... 42 more
```

I've decompiled the servlet-api.jar in Tomcat lib folder and verified getVirtualServerName() method is already there inside that class.

Please help anyone in rectifying this, what else need to check?

Comment: My guess is that there are multiple versions of the servlet-API JAR (or similar) on the effective classpath.  And one of them has an older `ServletContext` class that doesn't define that method.  (The method was introduced in the Servlet 3.1 spec.)

Comment: Indeed. Your runtime classpath is corrupted. The #1 starters mistake is providing duplicate different versioned server-specific libraries via webapp's WEB-INF/lib. You're not the first one stumbling upon this problem. See the abovelinked duplicate for several clues and solutions. I found it by just copy pasting your question title into a search engine (Google in my case). Excellent title thus, but try to do a bit more research in the future. Do not assume that you're the only one in the world making a starter's mistake.

Comment: FYI, "core Java" is not a thing, and if it were, servlets wouldn't be part of it, because it isn't provide by Java out-of-the-box (i.e. "the core of Java"), but requires additional libraries and runtimes (like Tomcat).

Comment: @BalusC : I've removed all the jars inside WEB-INF/lib and still getting the same error. Could you please help

Comment: Also, same setup is working fine on Linux environment

Comment: Then either Tomcat/lib or JDK/lib or JRE/lib is corrupted. Still boils down to the same problem. Remove conflicting files which were manually placed/edited in these folders. In case you have no clue simply remove/reinstall and then don't touch these.

Comment: Okay Thanks, I changed the JAVA_HOME to fresh JDK installation and it's working now